# Lists of description appropriate for formal writing?

Tags: style, academic-writing, essay

In a formal piece, is it appropriate to write a list, especially one of descriptions? It's the easiest way to get information across sometimes, especially on a tight word limit.

For example, if I had to describe a person, could I say these (would it be too non-creative and boring or is it okay?):

> He was a sophomore, a student from the Bagong school in Fujian.
>
> His parents were a successful, rich couple, which led to his great education.
>
> He was tall, skinny, with near-black eyes and rectangular glasses- very much like me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a list like that only makes sense if after presenting the list you then pick up each of the list items and discuss them or compare them to another list.

Formating must be meaningful, and a list serves a specific purpose. You don't just present sentences in a list for no reason, that woud confuse your readers.